# Set equation answer to two decimal in PHP

Tags: php

```
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
    echo "Total Profit = RM ". $row['SUM(profit)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
echo"</br>";
echo "<b><u>Total Profit earned </u></b>" ;
echo"</br>";
$query1 = "SELECT country, SUM(profit) FROM `table 1` GROUP BY country"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "". $row['country']. " = RM ". $row['SUM(profit)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

My code works but I need to set my Profit to 2 decimal places. Instead of `RM 373037194.867713152`, i want it to show it as `RM 373037194.87`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with round()

```
echo "". $row['country']. " = RM ". round($row['SUM(profit)'], 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
round($row['SUM(profit)'], 2); // round to two decimal places
```